# Glade GtkFileChooserDialog is selecting both folders and files

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, filechooser

I'm using Glade and GTK3 to build my Python 3 UI, and am using a GtkFileChooserDialog to select a file. But this dialog, even though my Action is set to Open, is allowing me to select folders as well. If I double-click on a folder, it opens it and allows me to search further for my file. But if I have a folder selected and type Enter or click the OK button, it returns that folder name. I want it to ONLY be able to return a file with a particular extension.

I see other posts where they have a hard time allowing selection of either a file or a folder, and most solutions talk about adding another button. But here I'm getting that behavior but don't want it.

Before I transferred my program over to a Glade interface I got the desired behavior. So is there some setting in Glade that I need to tweak to NOT return folders from my chooser? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Note that I can go back to the non-Glade way of running the dialog (and that's the way I currently have it in the code, to get the desired behavior), but what's the point of defining FileChooserDialogs in Glade if you don't have sufficient control over them?

Comment: If you have some code, which  makes folders not OKable, you can apply it to the widget you get from `.ui`. By the way, can you add your current code to the question?